# Difference between resolving a query and creating an endpoint with IP and port (in boost asio)

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I've recently noticed a problem with my application and I think it's due to the fact that I don't use `boost::asio` properly and don't understand what a tcp resolver does.

Basically, I use a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver` to get endpoints to connect to.

What I found out recently is that it can come up with more than one endpoint (in particular when I connect to the localhost).

At the moment I request an `async_connect` on all end point. I'm not a 100% sure but I think that's bad. I should go to them one by one an request an async_connect, wait for the reply and try on the next one if and only if it failed.

So basically knowing that I have two choices if I want to use `async_connect` on those end points:

1. refactor my code so that my `async_connect` handle failure properly and on failure try to connect to the other available endpoint. I would have to pass the endpoint iterator then.
2. Drop the resolver and use a endpoint I construct myself like this: `boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint("localhost", 20015)`

I kind of have a feeling that I should use the first solution and that the resolver is bringing something more than the self constructed endpoint.

But what does the resolver bring, and how does the self constructed endpoint resolve it self?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While Sam succinctly answered how most applications handle endpoint creation, I wanted to expand upon the [`resolver`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/resolver.html).

The `resolver` is used to convert human-readable text representations of an address into `endpoint`(s) that contains the structured binary format for an address via [hostname resolution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node35.html) or conversions between defined representations.  For example, the `resolver` may resolve the human-readable `"localhost"` to `0x7F000001` or convert `"127.0.0.1"` into `0x7F000001`.  Boost.Asio uses or emulates [`getaddrinfo()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo) to perform this resolution.  For asynchronous resolution, an internal thread will be created to perform the operation.

On the other hand, a [`basic_endpoint`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/basic_endpoint.html) does not resolve itself. While it cannot be constructed with a string and port, it can be constructed with an [`ip::address`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address.html) and port.  The `ip::address` can be constructed from a string in dotted decimal form (IPv4) or hexadecimal notation (IPv6):

```
namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 20015);
```

Providing a hostname to [`ip::address::from_string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/from_string.html) will throw an exception:

```
namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
ip::address::from_string("localhost"); // throws boost::system::system_error
```

In the end, use:

- `resolver` when you want to support hostname resolution or IP conversions.  This is especially convenient when IPs may change but hostnames remain the same, or when a single hostname may resolve to multiple IPs.
- `ip::address::from_string()` to create an address from an IP.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that connecting to all endpoints returned from the resolve operation is not likely what your application expects. Choice #2 will not work since there is no constructor for a `basic_endpoint(const char*, int)`. Choice #1 is how several asio examples are structured, notably the [async tcp client demonstrating timeouts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp).

Refactoring your code to include the `endpoint_iterator` returned from the resolver should not be too difficult, follow the example above if you have trouble. Note that it uses a blocking `resolve()` and not `async_resolve()`, the concept is the same however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful. I found out nevertheless that using async resolve was erratic (my platform is window and I quite often get `WSA_OPERATION_ABORTED` error `995`). So I opted for an intermediate solution with synchronous resolve and an iterative asynchronous connect on each end point, and yes refactoring my code was easy.